# "An error occurred while looking up roles in the group" after creating groups in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups

I have a very simple function that checks if a google (workspace) group exists and if not creates it.

This part works perfectly (group is created and I see it in the google admin dashbard) but if the same function is run again (on the now created group) it fails with the very unspecific error: `An error occurred while looking up roles in the group: mygroupname@mydomain.at`

My best guess was that because the group was created empty it had some problems when accessing the roles but I joined a test group and am still getting the same error.

Here's my simple function:

```
function createGroupIfNotExists(email)
{
  try
  {
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(email);
    console.log(" [i+] Group "+email+" Found!");
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(" [i-] Group "+email+" Not found.. creating");
    var emailObj = {
           "email":  email,
            "name": "Group "+email,
           "description": "the new group of "+email
          }
    var newGroup = AdminDirectory.Groups.insert( emailObj );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### `GroupsApp`documentation specifies: [A group object whose members and those members' roles within the group can be queried.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group)

If you create a group without member roles, you cannot retrieve it with the GroupsApp - use `AdminDirectory.Groups.get(email)` instead:

```js
function createGroupIfNotExists(email)
{
  try
  {
    var group = AdminDirectory.Groups.get(email)// GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(email);
    console.log(" [i+] Group "+email+" Found!");
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(" [i-] Group "+email+" Not found.. creating");
    var emailObj = {
           "email":  email,
            "name": "Group "+email,
           "description": "the new group of "+email
          }
    var newGroup = AdminDirectory.Groups.insert( emailObj );
  }
}
```